# how do i link to static html file without vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I'm new vue user, and English is not my native language, so i'll try my best to explain my question, thanks.

in the past time if i want to link root html file, i will add a tag like this `<a href="./other/other.html>`,it's structure like int this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6GVf.png)
and now i created a project with webpack vue-cli, but after i click a tag, url change to `localhost:8080/other/other.html` and nothing happened,the content is still index.html, only url changes.

is there any way to link to static html file or something i make mistake?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please paste the exact code of your <a> tag, how does it look?

Comment: like this <a href="./src/other/other.html">other</a> , and this tag is in app.vue

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute urls in your anchor tags, like this:

```
<a href="https://localhost:8080/other/other.html"></a>
```